# Making intuitively sense of Stochastic processes

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I've recently started self-studying stochastic processes. However i have yet to really understand intuitively what a stochastic process really is. From my understanding a stochastic process is (losely) defined as a family of stochastic variables, and where all of these stochastic variables are defined on the same sample space $\Omega$. A couple of questions arrive out of this:

1. Does this mean that all of the stochastic variables $ X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ has to have the same distribution function?
2. Suppose that we throw a dice 5 times and define one stochastic variable for each throw. Can this be considered as a stochastic process?
3. Suppose that we define $X(t) = A\cos(t)$, and we let A be a stochastic variable such that $A>0$. Can this also be considered a stochastic process even though we get a function, which is deterministic for each t?

Apart from this i also have quite a hard time understanding what the family of finite-dimensional distributions are and how to make sense of them. The book that im reading states that the statistical properties of a stochastic process are determined by the family of finite-dimensional distributions, but i have a hard time understanding why and what they really are.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I wouldn't even make an attempt to explain stochastic process is ( question is too broad ) but I remember this book providing a lucid explanation. https://www.amazon.com/Stationary-Related-Stochastic-Processes-Application/dp/0471183903/ref=sr_1_1?crid=35QRUNZFFJDRA&keywords=cramer+and+leadbetter&qid=1657403775&sprefix=cramer+and+leadbetter%2Caps%2C64&sr=8-1 Note that you also didn't state what your background in math is which kind of matters as far as what book to recommend. I'm not a mathematician and this book was quite clear for me.

Comment: 1. no, 2. yes, 3. yes and you don't even need the random $A$ before. Even $cos$ as function is a random process, a quite boring one though of course, since actually not being random at all. If $X_{t}$ is a process indexed over some set $T$ then the finite dimensional distributions are the multivariate random variables of the form $(X_{t_{1}},\dots, X_{t_{n}})$, for some $t_{i}\in T$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Tobsn Could you think of the finite dimensional distributions as kinda limiting the path the process can take? Does that make any sense?

Comment: I would rather think of it as taking snaphots of your process at $n$ different time points. A photo album (with infinitely many pages) containing all thoses sequences of snapshots is determining the process.